# How to pass array of string as parameters in swagger ui

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

Below is the REST api which i want to document using Swagger UI

```
  @ApiOperation(
              nickname = "alertForBundleId",
              value = "alertForBundleId",
              notes = "",
              httpMethod = "GET")
  def alertForBundleId(
                @ApiParam(name = "mfr", value = "Manufacturer", required = true) @PathParam("mfr") mfr: String,
                @ApiParam(name = "col", value = "Columns", required = true) @QueryParam("col") cols: List[String])){...}
```

Here cols parameter is accepting List of string.
When i pass two elements for the list separating by new line, then its generates url like 
 ?**col=sysid%2Calert_id**
while it should be like 
**?col=sysid&col=alert_id**
it works well for single element list
Any help will be greatly appreciated.